# How to use script and styles in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress. I need to create a new plugin for my website. How to I add scripts and styles for plugins. Advance thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register your scripts and styles by using the wp_register_script() function. See the examples below:

```
<?php
function wpb_adding_scripts() {
wp_register_script('my_amazing_script', plugins_url('amazing_script.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
wp_enqueue_script('my_amazing_script');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_scripts' );  
?>
```

Use bellow function for add styles in WordPress.

```
function your_function_name() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', plugins_url( 'put your css file path', __FILE__ ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_function_name' );
```

If you want to add custom java script code, use below code (But is bad)

```
function admin_load_js() { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        //add your code here
    </script>

<?php }

add_action('admin_head', 'admin_load_js');
```

Comment: can u say how to use styles in wordpress?

Comment: say one example to write inside amazing_script.js.

Comment: i wrote something like this, <script type="text/javascript">

function wpb_adding_scripts(){


alert('hello there this is a test popup')

}
</script>
<body onload="wpb_adding_scripts()">
</body>. but its not working..

Comment: Use bellow code it will work (but is bad) :                                                        function admin_load_js() { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
     //add your code here
    </script>

<?php }

add_action('admin_head', 'admin_load_js');

Comment: What you said already is fine.. But whatever i give inside amazing_script.js file is not working.. i just want to give alert message when the page is load..

Comment: I just  want to call amazing_script.js file in main file of wordpress.

Comment: If I add javascript for my wordpress plugin,  it shows the content to all pages of wordpress like post, page, media, etc..

Comment: how to add javascript and style to my plugin page itself in wordpress